# Sound not correctly detected with KY-037 and Rasberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, gpio

I have the KY-037 sound sensor with three jumpers going to the Ras Pi.

1. Ground - going to PIN 6
2. Out - going to PIN 7
3. VCC - going to PIN 2 (5v) I tried it on 3.3v (PIN 1) as well

I am running a program using Python on the Pi Zero. I want to send a text to my Twilio number but right now I am just trying to print the PIN and fire off a "sound detected" print statement when sound occurs.

HERE IS MY CODE:

````
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from twilio.rest import Client

# Twilio account information
account_sid = "123123123"
auth_token = "123123123"
twilio_number = "5551351234"
destination_number = "1121231122"

# Sound sensor configuration
sensor_pin = 4

# Set the pin numbering mode so the pin will be 4 instead of 7
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Set the sensor pin as an input
GPIO.setup(sensor_pin, GPIO.IN)

# Initialize the Twilio client
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


while True:

 # Read the sound sensor value
    value = GPIO.input(sensor_pin)

    # Use the value to determine whether a sound has occurred
    if value == 1:
        # A sound has occurred, so send a text message using Twilio
        print ("Sound Detected")
        
       #this will send a message to my Twilio account 
        #message = client.messages.create(to=destination_number, from_=twilio_number, body="Sound detected!")

    # Wait a little bit before checking again
    time.sleep(0.1) ```
````

Comment: A quick google search says the GPIO are not 5V tolerant. You may have damaged your Raspberry Pi. Try shorting the GPIO pin to ground or 3.3V to test if you can read a change from software.

Comment: I started with 3.3v pin and received the same results as the 5v pin. I do not clearly understand what you mean by  "shorting the GPIO pin to ground or 3.3V to test if you can read a change from software."

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi Zero, connect pin 7 to pin 6 and check that `GPIO.input(sensor_pin)` returns 0. Then connect pin 7 to pin 1 and check that `GPIO.input(sensor_pin)` returns 1. If you don't see these expected return values, then either your board is broken or your GPIO setup isn't right (sorry, I don't know Pi setup).